# Кодировка в базе данных

Tags: кодировка, база-данных, php, mysql

Вот так создаю таблицу в базе

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `test` CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci;

CREATE TABLE `test`.`orders` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`title` VARCHAR( 100 ) NOT NULL ,
`count` DECIMAL( 10,3 ) NOT NULL ,
`price` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL ,
`sum` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM ;
```

Страница сайта в кодировке 1251

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

При соединении с базой данных выполняю запрос:

```
SET CHARACTER SET cp1251
```

Протестировал в денвере все работает.

Залил на сервер - все перестало работать.

Как сделать, чтобы сайт работал везде? Мне его высылать нужно человеку, а я не знаю какие у него настройки.

Так же на сайте используется `ajax`, который тоже глючит.

И еще вопрос: в какой кодировке лучше хранить в базе? Обязательное условие - сайт должен быть в  `charset=windows-1251`

Comment: SET NAMES utf8 не пробовали?

Comment: > обязательное условие сайт должен быть в charset=windows-1251

а зачем? Байты экономите?

Comment: пробовал...

Comment: А как выбор кодировки в базе соотносится с выбором кодировки на веб-странице? Если они разные, ну перекодируйте, в чём проблема?

Comment: А вообще описание проблемы "всё перестало работать" ужасно. Телепаты в отпуске, постарайтесь сформулировать, что именно происходит не так, как вы ожидали.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать указать кодировку полей

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`orders` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
`title` VARCHAR( 100 )  CHARACTER SET cp1251 COLLATE cp1251_general_ci NOT NULL ,
`count` DECIMAL( 10,3 ) NOT NULL ,
`price` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL ,
`sum` DECIMAL( 10,2 ) NOT NULL 
) ENGINE = MYISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=cp1251;
```

Вообще в вашем случае дело может быть не в БД. ВЫ уверены, что страницы отдаются в CP1251, а не UTF8? Т.е. вы уверены, что на вашем сервере UTF8 не является кодировкой по умолчанию для страниц text/html?

Comment: так я прописал .htaccess

DefaultLanguage ru

AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

php_value default_charset "cp1251"

Comment: А сам файл, который вы заливаете? у вас в какой кодировке? Бывает, что помогает перекодирование дампа 
(делается, например так: 
iconv -fUTF8 -tCP1251 dump.sql > dump1.sql
)

Comment: таблица пустая, я добавляю записи

если не трудно посмотрите пожалуйста исходник

http://123.onfind.net/new_www.zip

Comment: Посмотрел.
В файле classes/prices.class.php в строке 13 замените 
$this->title=functions::sql(trim($_POST['title']));
на
$this->title=functions::sql(trim(iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1251', $_POST['title'])));
Все заработает.
Ajax запросы ВСЕГДА в UTF-8. Если вы используете cp1251 на сайте, то обязательно нужно перекодировать Ajax запросы и ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно я не прав.
localhost:3306/yourDb?characterEncoding=utf8